# How should I understand the dialogue between David and Weyland in Alien: Covenant's prologue?

Tags: dialogue, alien-covenant

There is a dialogue between David and Weyland when they were talking about who created who at the beginning of *Alien: Covenant*. David then said:

> Allow me then a moment to consider. You seek your creator. I am looking at mine. I will serve you. Yet you're human. You will die. I will not.

But what did he mean? Why did he say that to Weyland?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## David is demonstrating the irony of the situation.

Humans are seeking their creators, David already has done so.

David serves humans, despite them being inferior (as they will die, but David won't).

This is the beginning of David's contempt for humans, and introduces his motives for his actions in the remainder of the movie: creating the aliens by mixing humans and the evolutionary plague made by the Engineers.

Comment: So his contempt is connected with the fact that he realizes himself as a more highly developed creature than a human, but is forced to serve a human in the same time?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Well put ^^